# Jetty - alter order of request headers

Tags: java, header, request, jetty

It seems that jetty alter the order of the headers received. I collect them using `getHeaderNames()` on a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` object.

Do you know if there is a way to get them in the same order as they are set in the request?

Comment: For what purpose? It isn't defined in the HTTP RFCs. How can you possibly have a need to rely on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question, the headers are stored in an array in the order of the request. However, the method `getHeaderNames()` build an set based on each element of the array. The set does not keep the order of the elements.

One solution to by-pass this problem is to overwrite the method `getFieldNamesCollection()` of the class `org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpFields`, using an `LinkedHashSet` instead of a `HashSet`.

Another solution, with less impact would be to write a static custom
method `getHeaderNames()`, something like this :

```
static public String buildHeaderList(ServletRequest request){
    StringJoiner headerList = new StringJoiner(",");

    Request req = (Request) request;
    HttpFields fields = req.getMetaData().getFields();

    for (HttpField f : fields)
    {
        if (f!=null)
            headerList.add(f.getName());
    }

    return headerList.toString();
}
```

The request object is the type of `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request`

There are maybe other, more elegant, solutions. Please, feel free to add any.

Answer (score 0):

Header order is only guaranteed within the same Header name (per the HTTP spec and Servlet spec).

Meaning ...

```
Host: localhost
Cookie: foo
Cookie: bar
Cookie: baz
Accept: gzip
```

Using `getHeaderNames()` will just return the unordered collection of header names `[Cookie, Host, Accept]`

But `getHeaders("Cookie")` will return the order `[foo, bar, baz]`

Comment: Hi Joakim, thanks for the answer. My goal is to get the ordered list of headers not the values of them. I'm aware that the order of header is not guaranteed by HTTP/1.1 specs but for a specific need I'd like to get it. It seems that `getHeaderNames()` will always return the headers in the same order, but not in the one from the request so I was wondering if maybe there is a way to achieve that

Comment: As stated, the Servlet spec does not support this.  This truth is also applies under SPDY and HTTP/2.  Know also that intermediaries (proxies, load balancers, etc) can change the order to suite their own needs.